# Как реализовать поиск содержимого в файлах всех вложенных папок?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть структура папок, вложенных друг в друга.
Вот она:
[image]

В каждой из директорий есть вложенный xml файл defaultVars, в котором есть тэг hostname
Хочу вводить конкретный hostname через input или аргумент, и выполнять поиск по всем папкам в файле defaultvars.

Вывод на экран: путь к файлу.

Каким образом реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для рекурсивного поиска файлов можно воспользоваться `pathlib`.

После нахождения нужных файлов, открываем их и ищем нужные данные, если находим, то печатаем на экран путь к этому файлу.

***Код:***

```
import pathlib

directory = r'...'
file = r'...'
tag = r'...'

for path in pathlib.Path(directory).rglob(file):
    with open(path) as f:
        if tag in f.read():
            print(path)
```

**P. S.:**
**UPD:**

Допустим есть следующая структура папок (корневая папка - `lib`):

```html
├───path1
├───path2
│   └───path2_1
│       └───path2_1_1
└───path3
```

Я поместил в эти папки много разных файлов с разными расширениями.
Нужные мне файлы лежат: в корне, в `path1` и в `path2_1_1`, их расширение `.txt`

Допустим мне даже не известно их название, в этом тоже нет проблемы. Просто найдём все `.txt` файлы и произведём поиск в них. Условимся, что нужные данные это конструкция:
`<some>Hello!<tag>`

Также, я хочу напечатать искомую строку и 2 предыдущие.

Вот код для такого поиска:

```
import pathlib


directory = r'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\lib'
file = r'*.txt'
tag = r'<some>Hello!<tag>'

for path in pathlib.Path(directory).rglob(file):
    with open(path) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            if tag in lines[i]:
                print(f'Путь: {path}\n'
                       'Строки:')
                if i == 0:
                    print(lines[0])
                elif i == 1:
                    print(*lines[:2], sep='')
                else:
                    print(*lines[i-2:i+1], sep='')
```

`*.txt` - это все файлы с расширением *`.txt`*.

В итоге на экран выведутся пути ко всем 3 файлам и нужные строки.

Comment: Спасибо.
Но в некоторых папках, например C:Vars\Connections\Starts\ не одна вложенная папка, как в Anyway\Https\Identity, а несколько.Например (на основе AnyWay)Anyway\Https\Identity\Home\Instance\defaultVars
И файлы вложенные во все последующие папки поиск не выдает.

Comment: @Евгений Я очень плохо понимаю вложенность Ваших папок, но одно знаю точно - этот поиск рекурсивен. Он обойдёт все папки, подпапки и файлы в `directory` , найдя в них `file`, после чего откроет каждый и произведёт в нём поиск по `tag`. Я проверил, всё работает с большой вложенностью и сложной структурой папок.

Comment: @nomnons12 
При этом данный скрипт позволяет нам искать по ТЭГУ, а не по его содержанию... Я хочу искать по конкретному содержанию тэга... Если в тэге hostname значение= 192.168.1.0, тогда печатать, например. Можете помочь?

Comment: @Евгений Вы не правы. Этот скрипт ищет как раз по конкретному содержанию. Просто укажите вместо `tag` искомый текст. Я сейчас попробую пояснить ответ для большей наглядности.

Comment: Дошло! И правда, работает. Но если сможете написать подробнее, буду очень благодарен, как начинающий питонист))

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а будет ли работать данный скрипт, в случае если я буду искать не по  xml документу, а по обычному txt? Условно, у меня есть скрипт, который я выполняю, записываю в файл, и по нему хочу найти условно "Login"?

Comment: @Евгений Да. Я почти закончил с примером. Сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: спасибо, разобрался. Скажите пожалуйста, а если при поиске по файлу я хочу печатать не только путь, но и саму строку, в которой хранится результат (условно, строку с результатом и три предыдущие). print(tag.str) в данном случае не помогает.

Comment: @Евгений Тогда придётся немного изменить код, считывая не весь файл целиком, а построчно. Искать в каждой строке нужные данные и в случае нахождения печатать их. Я добавлю этот функционал в пример, чтобы стало нагляднее.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться!

Comment: а если я хочу печатать строку, в которой текст, и предыдущие 2? {line}+2?

Comment: @Евгений Тогда нужно переписать цикл и обращаться к строкам по индексу. Чтобы взять 2 предыдущие строки и искомую, используйте срез вида `[i-2:i]` к списку строк, где `i` - индекс искомой строки. Обновлю пример для вас.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы очень добры :) Буду погружаться!

Comment: Немного ошибся, индексация должна быть такая: `[i-2:i+1]`. Я уже добавил это в пример.

Comment: Спасибо, изучаю.

Comment: @Евгений В программе был баг. Она неправильно печатала строки, если индекс искомой был от 1 до 3. Исправил, добавив `if-elif-else`.

Comment: @Евгений Кстати, если ответ Вам помог, я был бы очень признателен, если бы Вы отметили его как правильный.

Comment: Конечно, помог. Отметил! Большое спасибо за Вашу помощь и подробные объяснения.